# Footer not sticking after several solutions have been tried

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I'm having trouble getting my footer to stick to the bottom of the page. It works in 1024x1280, which is what I'm designing for, but the #content section overlaps the footer and causes white space at the bottom of the window as soon as I test it in 1024x768 and 800x600. I've tried:

- Setting the footer position to absolute w/ bottom:0 ;
- Using position:fixed, which works, but overlaps the content. I want it to appear after the content.
- Adding padding to the container and pulling the footer up with a negative margin
- Adding padding to #content and pulling the footer up with a negative margin
- Using a horrible hacky #push div set to the same height as the footer

[Here's the page that's having the problem.](http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/about/)

At this point I'm about ready to throw some Jquery at it and be done, but if there's a CSS way to solve the problem I'm open to suggestions.

Edit: If things look a bit wonky for a moment, it's because I'm adding a plugin to stretch the background image. Pardon the mess!